# Kendo time picker with autocomplete

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using the kendo Time Picker, it has time intervals, intervals of 15. I now want to have an autocomplete on both the Start time and End time controls.

For an example, if a user types in 181, I want it to automatically set to 18:10.  Please see the images for clarity.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Please review my current code above, and what I should do please

Comment: You need to bind an event on that field's `keyup` or `focusout` and parse the typed time to check if it needs completion and if yes, perform an auto completion based on the partial value entered.